# creating singleton using GCD dispatc_once and ARC

Tags: ios, singleton, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I want to create singleton and I am not sure what to use: dispatch_once or @syncronized.

My question is: if I create singleton object (using GCD) on one view controller and then, I go to another view controller, Will ARC destroy my singleton object? If i will need it again in another view controller, can I create it again?

Answer (score 0):

If you create correctly, no one will destroy it, except killing the app, for this reason singleton should be used only for very specific tasks.

This is how I create singleton using ARC, it's a class method

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}
```

Calling +sharedInstance on your class will ensure that will be returned always the same object